# Client not able to receive messages from Server Socket programming Java

Tags: java, sockets

I am trying to make a chat system through terminal. One computer acts as server, the other as client.

Here is my code for Client side :

```
try
    (
        Socket s = new Socket(hostname,port);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(),true);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    ) {
        String input;

        while ((input = stdIn.readLine()) != null)
        {
            out.println(input);
        }


        String inputline;
        while ((inputline = in.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println("Them: " + inputline);
        }



        // out.close();
        // stdIn.close();
        // s.close();
    }
    catch (UnknownHostException e)
    {
        System.err.println("Don't know about host: " + hostname);
        System.exit(1);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O");
        System.exit(1);
    }
```

Here is my code for Server side:

```
System.out.println ("New communication thread started.");
        try
        {
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(),true);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

            BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String input;

            String inputline;
            while ((inputline = in.readLine()) != null)
            {
                System.out.println("Them: " + inputline);
            }

            while ((input = stdIn.readLine()) != null)
            {
                out.println(input);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException exx)
        {
            System.err.println("Some problem");
            System.exit(1);
        }
```

Comment: Can you tell us what your question is? What's going wrong with your code?

Comment: I am running the server code on one machine and the client code on another. The client messages are being received on the server end but when I type a message on terminal on the server side and hit enter, the message is not received by the client.

Comment: Have you some firewall?

Answer (score 2):

You are using `stdIn.readLine()` on `System.in` but that stream can never terminates (of course).
So you should change your condition.

```
while ((input = stdIn.readLine()) != null) // Your problem is here
```

Have you checked if you reach the second while?

Try this in both server and client:

```
 input = stdIn.readLine();
 out.println(input);
```

Comment: while ((input = stdIn.readLine()) != null)
   {
    out.println(input);
    System.out.println("Them: " + in.readLine());
   }

Comment: I made this change to the client code but now it obviously receives a message when it sends a message or vice versa
What to do to make message receiving instantaneous on both sides?

Comment: "but now it obviously receives" why is obviously? I think you are wrong.
The problem is the while until stdIn.readLine() returns null. It never will returns null. You have remove that while and get only 1 line

Comment: I solved it. Made threads to simultaneously send and receive messages.

Comment: OK, but you didn't ask that. You asked why you couldn't get the answer.. The problem  was that.

Comment: @ShardulTripathi for more about EOF on System.in read here: http://www.coderanch.com/t/279170/java-io/java/EOF-System